# How to solve "Specified cast is not valid" when I tried to connect database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am building an GUI and I used connection string to connect the sql server database, later I deleted the previous database and build a new one with different name, and change the connection string in app.config file. But after then it always showed that "Specified cast is not valid" and can't connect to DB anymore.
Could anyone can help how to connect to the Database again?

Comment: _Where_ does that error occur?  What type(s) are you trying to cast?  The cause is you're trying to cast a value of one type to an incompatible type, but that's the best answer that can be given without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AppSettings GUI or the project settings GUI to edit the app config. It's possible that you changed the name of the actual connection string and now the typed Settings class is no longer finding your setting.